# Vagrant - Passenger is not available from public IPs

Tags: vagrant, passenger

**Vagrant - Ubuntu 16.04 - Passenger(standalone with embedded nginx) - Ruby**

I intend to deploy a public server on my local machine via the above config.
It seemed everything worked, I test it from the local machine's browser and from mobile via the local wifi.
Then I tried from some other IP and from the same mobile via 4G and no success.

The vagrant config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
  # Using a private network seems to be slightly faster, but it's simpler to point a browser to a forwarded port, so I'll leave that as the default.

  config.vm.network :"public_network"

#  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'puppet/ubuntu.sh'

#  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
#    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
#    puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
#  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "off"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "off"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "12288", "--ioapic", "on", "--cpus", 4]
  end
```

Can somebody help me how can I reach my server from outside, what is the proper setting in this environment?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you were in the same IP class? You can put  an IP after `config.vm.network :"public_network", ip: "192.168.44.10"`

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa I get the ip via bash to avoid any mistake and used in the same time via the several method(from local IP and mobile through wifi and external IPs and 4G from mobile)